# What does the cast pointer do in this code?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, arduino

This function is supposed to convert an integer value to 32-bit float representation in hex.  But I don't understand what the 3rd line actually does.  Can anyone elaborate on that?

```
void convert_to_IEEE754( int value, char* ieee754_str ) {
  float ieee754_value = (float) value / 1000;  // value is pre-multiplied by 1000
  byte* array = (byte*) &ieee754_value;
  sprintf( ieee754_str, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", array[3], array[2], array[1], array[0] );
}
```

Comment: The third line `byte* array = (byte*) &ieee754_value;` is casting the values at the memory address occupied by `ieee754_value` to type `(byte*)` and assigning the address to `array` (which will have been declared somewhere earlier as unsigned-char or typedefed). This allows indexing of the 4-bytes in `ieee754_value` which are then written to `ieee754_str` via `sprintf`.

Comment: `byte` is no standard type. Why not use `unsigned char *`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: "... is casting the values at the memory address occupied by ..." – No. It casts the address of the `float` to a `byte *`, not the value.

Comment: Do you mean the 3rd line in your code or in the function ?

Comment: @Olaf byte was used I thought that's one of the standard types for Arduino: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Byte

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis 3rd line in my code.

Comment: @Olaf thank you, that is what I meant, but it is still before the 2nd cup of coffee here `:(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cast:

```
byte* array = (byte*) &ieee754_value;
```

converts the value `&ieee754_value` to the type `byte *`, so that it can be assigned to the variable `array`. Without the cast the expression `&ieee754_value` has type `float *` and such a value cannot be assigned to a variable of type `byte *`. Thus the cast is necessary.

The `array` pointer is then used to read the bytes making up the value.

This is not a recommended technique, it's better to use a `union` for this:

```
union {
  float ieee754_value;
  byte  bytes[4];
} tmp = { .ieee754_value = (float) value / 1000 };
```

then access the bytes through `tmp.bytes`.